# How do I combine IOError exceptions with locally relevant exceptions?

Tags: haskell, exception

I am building a Haskell application and trying to figure out how I am going to build the error handling mechanism.  In the real application, I'm doing a bunch of work with Mongo.  But, for this, I'm going to simplify by working with basic IO operations on a file.

So, for this test application, I want to read in a file and verify that it contains a proper fibonnacci sequence, with each value separated by a space:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
```

Now, when reading the file, any number of things could actually be wrong, and I am going to call all of those [exceptions in the Haskell usage of the word](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_vs._Exception).

```
data FibException = FileUnreadable IOError
                  | FormatError String String
                  | InvalidValue Integer
                  | Unknown String

instance Error FibException where
    noMsg = Unknown "No error message"
    strMsg = Unknown
```

Writing a pure function that verifies the sequence and throws an error in the case that the sequence is invalid is easy (though I could probably do better):

```
verifySequence :: String -> (Integer, Integer) -> Either FibException ()
verifySequence "" (prev1, prev2) = return ()
verifySequence s (prev1, prev2) =
    let readInt = reads :: ReadS Integer
        res = readInt s in
    case res of
        [] -> throwError $ FormatError s
        (val, rest):[] -> case (prev1, prev2, val) of
            (0, 0, 1) -> verifySequence rest (0, 1)
            (p1, p2, val') -> (if p1 + p2 /= val'
                then throwError $ InvalidValue val'
                else verifySequence rest (p2, val))
            _ -> throwError $ InvalidValue val
```

After that, I want the function that reads the file and verifies the sequence:

```
type FibIOMonad = ErrorT FibException IO

verifyFibFile :: FilePath -> FibIOMonad ()
verifyFibFile path = do
    sequenceStr <- liftIO $ readFile path
    case (verifySequence sequenceStr (0, 0)) of
        Right res -> return res
        Left err -> throwError err
```

This function does exactly what I want if the file is in the invalid format (it returns `Left (FormatError "something")`) or if the file has a number out of sequence (`Left (InvalidValue 15)`).  But it throws an error if the file specified does not exist.

How do I catch the IO errors that readFile may produce so that I can transform them into the FileUnreadable error?

As a side question, is this even the best way to do it?  I see the advantage that the caller of `verifyFibFile` does not have to set up two different exception handling mechanisms and can instead catch just one exception type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Savanni D'Gerinel: you are on the right track. Let's extract your error-catching code from *verifyFibFile* to make it more generic, and modify it slightly so that it works directly in ErrorT:

```
catchError' :: ErrorT e IO a -> (IOError -> ErrorT e IO a) -> ErrorT e IO a
catchError' m f =
    ErrorT $ catchError (runErrorT m) (fmap runErrorT f)
```

*verifyFibFile* can now be written as:

```
verifyFibFile' :: FilePath -> FibIOMonad ()
verifyFibFile' path = do
    sequenceStr <- catchError' (liftIO $ readFile path) (throwError . FileUnReadable)
    ErrorT . return $ verifySequence sequenceStr' (0, 0)
```

Notice what we have done in *catchError'*. We have stripped the ErrorT constructor from the `ErrorT e IO a` action, and also from the return value of the error-handling function, knowing than we can reconstruct them afterwards by wrapping the result of the control operation in ErrorT again.

Turns out that this is a common pattern, and it can be done with monad transformers other than ErrorT. It can get tricky though (how to do this with ReaderT for example?). Luckily, the [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) packgage already provides this functionality for many common transformers.

The type signatures in monad-control can seem scary at first. Start by looking at just one function: [control](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/0.3.1.4/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v%3acontrol). It has the type:

```
control :: MonadBaseControl b m => (RunInBase m b -> b (StM m a)) -> m a
```

Let's make it more specific by making `b` be `IO`:

```
control :: MonadBaseControl IO m => (RunInBase m IO -> IO (StM m a)) -> m a
```

*m* is a monad stack built on top of *IO*. In your case, it would be *ErrorT IO*.

`RunInBase m IO` is a type alias for a magical function, that takes a value of type `m a` and returns a value of type `IO *something*`, *something* being some complex magic that encodes the state of the whole monad stack inside IO and lets you reconstruct the `m a` value afterwards, once you have "fooled" the control operation that only accepts IO values. *control* provides you with that function, and also handles the reconstruction for you.

Applying this to your problem, we rewrite *verifyFibFile* once more as:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control (control)
import Control.Exception (catch)


verifyFibFile'' :: FilePath -> FibIOMonad ()
verifyFibFile'' path = do
    sequenceStr <- control $ \run -> catch (run . liftIO $ readFile path) 
                                           (run . throwError . FileUnreadable)     
    ErrorT . return $ verifySequence sequenceStr' (0, 0)
```

Keep in mind that this only works when the proper instance of `MonadBaseControl b m` exists.

[Here](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/08/monad-control) is a nice introduction to monad-control.

Comment: I'll leave the control package alone for now.  I get what you are doing in the first part of this, but why does unwrapping the operation and then wrapping the entire catchError in an ErrorT give me the flow of operations that I was looking for while lifting catchError does not?  Can you explain the difference?

Comment: What liftIO does in an `ErrorT IO` context is to take a value type `IO a`, turn it into an `IO (Either e a)` by wrapping the `a` value within a `Right` (the Right constructor means "no error effect" for ErrorT) and then wrap the IO action as a whole in the ErrorT constructor.
Your catch statement had type `IO (Either e a)`. liftIO wrapped the entire `Either a` value within a `Right`,  getting something of type `IO (Either e (Either e a))`, and then applied the ErrorT constructor. The monad always encountered a Right just under the IO action and assumed that no error happened.

Comment: By the way, @singpolyma's recommendation to use the **errors** package is a good one. EitherT works just like ErrorT but imposes less constraints on the error type. The package has very useful combinators (like `hoistEither` and `fmapLT` in singpolyma's example) for dealing with errors, and using `tryIO` is a simpler alternative to monad-control. monad-control is best used when you have to lift control operations that require a callback, like `withFile` or `bracket`. `catch` does require a callback, but `try` does not, is more or less equivalent, and already returns an Either.

Comment: Oh, now I get it.  So, even if catch returned `Left (FileUnreadable blah)`, then liftIO would have simply wrapped a Right around that.  And, in fact, now I see that it did and that my `<-` basically unwrapped the Right from it.  So, your solution passes `Right $ readFile path` into `catchError'`.  `runErrorT` strips that off at whatever time that the operation actually gets evaluated.  This is still very difficult to comprehend, but I'm getting closer.  I've not even tried figuring out the `fmap runErrorT` portion, yet.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider `EitherT` and the `errors` package in general.  http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/errors/1.3.1/doc/html/Control-Error-Util.html has a utility `tryIO` for catching `IOError` in `EitherT` and you could use `fmapLT` to map error values to your custom type.

Specifically:

```
type FibIOMonad = EitherT FibException IO

verifyFibFile :: FilePath -> FibIOMonad ()
verifyFibFile path = do
    sequenceStr <- fmapLT FileUnreadable (tryIO $ readFile path)
    hoistEither $ verifySequence sequenceStr (0, 0)
```

Comment: I'm going to try to really internalize the stuff above, first.  This is so difficult that bringing in this as well is going to confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's an answer that I have developed.  It centers around getting `readFile` wrapped into the proper `catchError` statement, and then lifted.

```
verifyFibFile :: FilePath -> FibIOMonad ()
verifyFibFile path = do
    contents <- liftIO $ catchError (readFile path >>= return . Right) (return . Left . FileUnreadable)
    case contents of
        Right sequenceStr' -> case (verifySequence sequenceStr' (0, 0)) of
            Right res -> return res
            Left err -> throwError err
        Left err -> throwError err
```

So, `verifyFibFile` gets a little more nested in this solution.

`readFile path` has type `IO String`, obviously.  In this context, the type for `catchError` will be:

```
catchError :: IO String -> (IOError -> IO String) -> IO String
```

So, my strategy was to catch the error and turn it into the left side of an Either, and turn the successful value into the right side, changing my data type to this:

```
catchError :: IO (Either FibException String) -> (IOError -> IO (Either FibException String)) -> IO (Either FibException String)
```

I do this by, in the first parameter, simply wrapping the result into Right.  I figure that I won't actually execute the `return . Right` branch of the code unless `readFile path` was successful.  In the other parameter to catch, I start with an `IOError`, wrap it in `Left`, and then return it back into the `IO` context.  After that, no matter what the result is, I lift the IO value up into the `FibIOMonad` context.

I'm bothered by the fact that the code gets even more nested.  I have `Left` values, and all of those `Left` values get thrown.  I'm basically in an `Either` context, and I had thought that one of the benefits `Either`'s implementation of the `Monad` class was that `Left` values would simply be passed along through the binding operations and that no further code in that context would be executed.  I would love some elucidation on this, or to see how the nesting can be removed from this function.

Maybe it can't.  It does seem that the caller, however, can call `verifyFibFile` repeatedly and execution basically stops the first time `verifyFibFile` returns an error.  This works:

```
runTest = do
    res <- verifyFibFile "goodfib.txt"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "goodfib.txt"
    --liftIO $ printResult "goodfib.txt" res

    res <- verifyFibFile "invalidValue.txt"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "invalidValue.txt"

    res <- verifyFibFile "formatError.txt"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "formatError.txt"

Main> runErrorT $ runTest
goodfib.txt
Left (InvalidValue 17)
```

Given the files that I have created, both invalidValue.txt and formatError.txt cause errors, but this function returns `Left (InvalidValue ...)` for me.

That's okay, but I still feel like I've missed something with my solution.  And I have no idea whether I'll be able to translate this into something that makes MongoDB access more robust.